# How do I display base64 images in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, image, matplotlib, base64

Before I dive in, this must be done in memory without saving the images locally (if possible).

I have a matplotlib charts that were created via a for loop and encoded to base64 links. I want to be able to display the base64 links in the column Stacking Plan as images instead of in their current base64 format. Here is a link to view the table:

[Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24JjE.png)

Here is the code I used to convert my matplotlib charts into base64 links and then appended them to a list called stacks, which then got turned into a table:

```
my_stringIObytes = BytesIO()
plt.savefig(my_stringIObytes, format='png')
my_stringIObytes.seek(0)
my_base64_jpgData = base64.b64encode(my_stringIObytes.read()).decode()

stacks.append(my_base64_jpgData)
```

Then outside of my for loop is this to be able to add the plots to my summary table:

```
summary['Stacking Plan'] = stacks
```

The goal is to be able to show the dataframe with these charts as images. I don't have the ability to save the images and then load them in.

If there is a better way to do this overall I'm open to that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there.

I take that you are using a notebook (otherwise, you need to know how to render the table ; in a terminal, obviously, it would be very different)

But with jupyter, you can easily render HTML strings, with IPython

See my own [mre]

```py
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import HTML
import numpy as np
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
import base64

# A dataframe containing parameters for synthetic images
df=pd.DataFrame({'f1':[2,5], 'f2':[3, 1]})

# Some random images (I create the whole array of images)
# so a 4D array, with shape (len(df), 300, 300, 3)
# meaning len(df) 300×300 RGB images
x=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,300)[None,None,:,None]
y=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,300)[None,:,None,None]
phi=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,3)[None,None,None,:]
f1=df.f1.values[:,None,None,None]
f2=df.f2.values[:,None,None,None]
imgs = np.sin(f1*x+phi)*np.sin(f2*y*phi) # Why not this

# So, now my example is set up. I have a dataframe with n rows. And n images.
# Let's fill the column with base 64 images.
# For this I need an image->string conversion
# that generates the image in HTML
# That is almost your code
def toB64(img):
    pimg=Image.fromarray((img*127+128).astype(np.uint8))
    my_stringIObytes = BytesIO()
    pimg.save(my_stringIObytes, format='png')
    my_stringIObytes.seek(0)
    b64 = base64.standard_b64encode(my_stringIObytes.read()).decode()
    return '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'+b64+'">' 
    # Difference is that I add the "data:image/png;base64,", to turn this base64 string into a "URL" (not a "link": the image is in the URL)
    # And that I add <img src=url> to turn this URL into an HTML image

# I can now create a new column containing the base64 images
df['imgs'] = [toB64(img) for img in imgs]

# And render the table
HTML(df.to_html(escape=False))
```

The 2 important lines you are missing are the last of `toB64`, that create the img element from the base64 URL.
And the last, that renders the table with HTML (providing that you are in a notebook). `escape=False` meaning that content of strings that could be confused with html code are not escaped, as they usually are, and therefore treated as real HTML code by browser.

[image]

Comment: this worked! Do you know how to make the column widths on the HTML table all the same?

Comment: @katie You can control the width of image by adding a `width=` to the `img`. So, use `return '<img width=100 src="data:image/png;base64,'+b64+'">'`  for example

Comment: And you can also partially control the width of other columns, by adding a `col_space` parameter to `to_html`. So `HTML(df.to_html(escape=False, col_space=[100,100,100]))`. I said "partially" because that controls `min width`, not max. So it can still be bigger (which is what happens to image column, if image is big, unless you reduce it with the `width` parameter)